# Speeding up algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

TL;DR: My code is "fast" in Java but slow as hell in C++. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

int read(string data, int depth, int pos, vector<long>& wantedList) {
    // 91 = [
    if (data.at(pos) == 91) {
        pos++;
        // Get first part
        pos = read(data, depth + 1, pos, wantedList);
        // Get second part
        pos = read(data, depth + 1, pos, wantedList);
    } else {
        // Get the weight
        long weight = 0;
        while (data.length() > pos && isdigit(data.at(pos))) {
            weight = 10 * weight + data.at(pos++) - 48;
        }
        weight *= 2 << depth;
        wantedList.push_back(weight);
    }
    return ++pos;
}


int doStuff(string data) {
    typedef map<long, int> Map;
    vector<long> wantedList;
    Map map;
    read(data, 0, 0, wantedList);
    for (long i : wantedList) {
        if (map.find(i) != map.end()) {
            map[i] = map[i] + 1;
        } else {
            map[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    vector<int> list;
    for (Map::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
        list.push_back(it->second);
    }
    sort(list.begin(), list.begin() + list.size());
    cout << wantedList.size() - list.back() << "\n";
    return 0;

}

int main() {
    string data;
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    for (int j = 0; j < i ; ++j) {
        cin >> data;
        doStuff(data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have just tried my first C++ project, and it's re-written code from Java.
The original task was to calculate how many numbers that needed to be changed in order to "balance" the input, given that each level above something weighs double the lower

eg [1,2] would need 1 change (either 1->2 or 2->1 in order to be equal on both sides and [8,[4,2]] would need 1 change (2->4) in order for the "lower level" to become 8 and therefore be of equal weight on the higher level. The problem can be found here for those who are interested:

[Problem link](https://open.kattis.com/problems/equilibrium)

And for those who wonder, this is a school assignment regarding algorithms, but I'm not asking for help with that, since I have already completed it in Java. The problem is that my algorithm seem to be pretty shit when it comes to C++.

In Java I get times around 0.6 seconds, and in C++, the "same" code gives >2 seconds (time limit exceeded).

Anyone care to give me a pointer as to why this is? I was under the impression that C++ is supposedly faster than Java when it comes to these type of problems.

Comment: Why are you using a recursive approach?? Why not just trying to read as much data as possible into a prepared (`resize()`d) `std::vector<long>`?

Comment: This might be a better fit on the [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. That said, since you're new to C++, did you turn on compiler optimizations? Java got them on by default, but for C++ you usually have to enable them.

Comment: how big is `data`? You're copying it all over the place

Comment: you may want to pass your string by reference for beggining.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x The ints on each level are <10^9 and there are maximum 16 "levels", but I don't have any specific details on the testcases, or the number of cases, since testing is done by the site giving the problem.

Comment: You do not need `list` at all. You're sorting all of the values in `map` and then taking the largest. You could simply get the largest value in `map` with `std::max_element`. You could also use a `std::unordered_map` if you don't need it sorted by key, which is probably a better reflection of your Java code.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl The site only lets me input text, so I don't think I can change the compiler optimization, but thanks for the tip (since I had them set to "low" in my own compiler :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't really understand how not to use it recursively, since I don't know the exact input data. I did the same recursion in Java, and it worked excellent.

Comment: FWIW, `if (map.find(i) != map.end()) {
            map[i] = map[i] + 1;
        } else {
            map[i] = 1;
        }` could simply be `++map[i]` since a 0 is inserted by `operator[]` if the key isn't in there already.

Comment: @nikolap Haha, thanks man! That cut the time from >2  to 0.13

Comment: @chris This shaved away another 0.01, so that's nice.
I get that it's good not to use an unnecessary vector, so thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of possible reasons is copying.

Whenever you pass something by value in C++ a copy is created. For tings like `double`, `int` or a pointer, that's not a problem.

But for objects like `std::string` copying may be expensive. Since you don't modify `data` it makes sense to pass it by const reference:

```
int read(const string &data, int depth, int pos, vector<long>& wantedList)
```